# Deploying Java application on Tomcat 7 with Context Versioning

Tags: tomcat, java, deployment, tomcat7

I am working on an API that is built on top of the Spark mini-framework (http://sparkjava.com/)

Whenever I build a package through Maven, which is then uploaded to the webapps/ folder under Tomcat 7.

(The real name have been replaced with TestProject to avoid disclosing anything propritary)

If I compile the project and name it TestProject.war, it is loaded with the following information:

**Path**: /TestProject

**Version**: *None specified*

Upon opening http://localhost:8080/TestProject/ I then get the expected output:

> {"code":400,"message":"The authorization information was not specified
>   in the request"}

If I then rename the file to TestProject##0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_20160308.161909.war and restart Tomcat, the application is loaded with the following details:

**Path**: /TestProject

**Version**: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_20160308.161909

Unfortunately, when opening the same url, Tomcat returns 404:

> HTTP Status 404 - /
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** /
>
> **description** The requested resource is not available. Apache
>
> Tomcat/7.0.67

```
$ cat web.xml

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>RESTFul Web Service</display-name>    

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
            <param-value>TestProjectService</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,authorization,scope,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>

$ cat context.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="true" path="/TestProject"/>
```

I simply don't know what causes the problem.. The only difference is the name of the .war

**System information:**

```
OS: Windows 10 x64
Java: java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

C:\OtherPrograms\apache-tomcat-7.0.67>bin\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\OtherPrograms\apache-tomcat-7.0.67"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\OtherPrograms\apache-tomcat-7.0.67"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\OtherPrograms\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\OtherPrograms\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\OtherPrograms\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```